# Youtube comments extraction API V3

Tags: python, youtube

I am using this code but it's not working as it is for API v2, please provide the code for extracting youtube comments.

```
import gdata.youtube.service
yts = gdata.youtube.service.YouTubeService()
ytfeed = yts.GetYouTubeVideoCommentFeed(video_id="pXhcPJK5cMc")
comments = [comment.content.text for comment in ytfeed.entry]
```

Comment: Please provide us what have you done to convert this code to API V3

Comment: M Trying to use:

def get_comments(youtube, parent_id):
  results = youtube.comments().list(
    part="snippet",
    parentId=parent_id,
    textFormat="plainText"
  ).execute()

  for item in results["items"]:
    author = item["snippet"]["authorDisplayName"]
    text = item["snippet"]["textDisplay"]
    print "Comment by %s: %s" % (author, text)

  return results["items"]

as given at developers.google

Bt not able to run this command as running the function gives :name 'youtube' is not defined

Answer (score 1):

To extract YouTube video comments using YouTube API v.3, you need some Python code like this:

```
def get_video_comments(service, **kwargs):
    comments = []
    results = service.commentThreads().list(**kwargs).execute()

    while results:
        for item in results['items']:
            comment = item['snippet']['topLevelComment']['snippet']['textDisplay']
            comments.append(comment)

        # Check if another page exists
        if 'nextPageToken' in results:
            kwargs['pageToken'] = results['nextPageToken']
            results = service.commentThreads().list(**kwargs).execute()
        else:
            break

    return comments
```

For more details about this code and how to use YouTube API to search for videos using a keyword and then save comments to a CSV file, you can check this tutorial: https://python.gotrained.com/youtube-api-extracting-comments/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the api, here's the another way.

tube_dl is a python downloader with comments extractor. Here is how to use.

```
pip install tube_dl
from tube_dl.comments import Comments
comment = Comments('youtube url').process_comments(count=45) #don't write count= for all comments
```

This module has been created by me. If you find any issues, please feel free to raise and issue at github.com/shekharchander/tube_dl